# Inserting a Word document content (with formatting) in a RDLC report using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-word, rdlc

I'm creating a `RDLC` report in C#. Is it possible to insert the content of  a ***Word 2003 document*** (with formatting) in it (either in design time or programmatically) before exporting to `PDF`. The final result will be a `PDF` file containing the initial report (fields from database) and the *Word document* content following it.

Why this? I need to give the user the possibility to fill a form, attach a word document and export the all to PDF as I described earlier (`ASP.NET`). I don't have Word installed on the server so I can't Interact with its COM objects.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Which format does the word document use? If it's .docx, you can try going with the [Open XML SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=C6E744E5-36E9-45F5-8D8C-331DF206E0D0&displaylang=en) from Microsoft.

Not sure about how to import the formatting.

Comment: unfortunately it's not a docx, a doc file (2003)

Answer (score 1):

This question was asked a long time ago, so I doubt this answer will be of much use to the OP, but if someone else stumbles across this as I did...

...I would think it should be fairly easy using a 3rd party component to convert the doc to an image and then use that in the RDLC without much hassle at all.